# VueJS list of various elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have tried and tried searching for the specific use-case I am after but alas, came up empty.
It could be that I am searching in the wrong direction, but here is the question:

Say I have an array of objects that contain, among other parameters, a title field and an input type field. With this array I would like to create a dialog from vuetify, in which I dynamically insert the relevant input elements based on the type field. This can be input, radio, checkbox but also something more exotic like cron scheduling.

So one way would be to set a slot in the dialog on where the input fields should come, but this requires coding on the child component which will implement such dialog. I was thinking more of something like a loop over the array of objects and rendering the specific component based on the type field, Something like a switch-case system.

Is this something I can do, and whether it is smart to do ? Would like to hear others opinions about this :)

Comment: probably you want to try [speical attr: is](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is), something like: `<div class="row" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"><component v-bind:is="item.inputType"></component></div>`;

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by creating a huge form that contains everything and not rendering unnecessary elements due to

```
v-if="inputType.includes('text')"
```

In this case, you can use text-1, text-2, text-n for rendering multiple form elements with the same types. I don't think adding is possible because even if you manage to add, how do you set the condition, v-modal, event bindings etc.